# of existing or an existing .Which is more correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english, programming

Extending functionalities of existing applications or Extending functionalities of an existing applications .Which is more correct?

Comment: ...an existing applications...?

Comment: If you have one application it's "of _an_ existing application", if you have more than one it's "of existing applications", "Of an existing applications" is as wrong as "the heads of a dogs" and for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you very much!